# Calculate limit of a sum as an integral

Tags: integration, riemann-sum

I need to calculate this limit as a definite integral but it doesn't look like Riemann sum at all:

[image]

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} n^2 \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(n + i + 1)^3} $$

What would be an approach to this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's an $x$ here?

Comment: Hint (I haven't tried). Think of the unit interval as divided into $n$ subintervals of length $1/n$. For what function would this Riemann sum be an approximation to the area? You may want to move the $n^2$ inside the summation.

Comment: @Ilya $x \in [x_{i-1}, x_{i}] $

Comment: your sum does not seem to depend on $x$ though

Comment: No, it is what should be in the end. There should be value of a function with some argument depending on $i$ multiplied by the interval, but I can't figure out what the function should look like.

Comment: If you write what you tried, I will give you a complete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L = $ \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^n\frac{n^2}{(n+i+1)^3}$ [taking n common from the denominator]

L = $ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{(1+\frac{i}{n}+\frac{1}{n})^3}$ [converting to integral]

L = $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{(1+x)^3}\, dx$

L = $\frac{3}{8}$ = 0.375